# How to play a jwplayer link on vlc?

Tags: flash, streaming, vlc, live, iptv

I get this link from a live streaming and i want to play it on vlc this is the link :

```
rtmp://stream.mediaforall.net:1935/liveorigin/<playpath>livestream_480p <swfUrl>http://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.8.7/jwplayer.flash.swf <pageUrl>h
```

what should i do to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the **stream** path (`<playpath>`) to the **server** path (`rtmp://..etc`).

Final path for using in VLC :

```
rtmp://stream.mediaforall.net:1935/liveorigin/livestream_480p
```